# Debug dotnet core process hanging at futex

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, gdb, futex

I am running a dotnet core 2.1 application on the following linux embedded system:

```
Linux arm 4.14.67-1.0.7+ #52 SMP PREEMPT armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The application hangs since a couple of days at a futex:

```
root@arm:/# strace -p 525
strace: Process 525 attached
futex(0x4a6f4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 29517, NULL
 <detached ...>
```

I must find out which line of c# code produces the corresponding futex call without stopping the process. How can I find the way back to the line of c# code that produces the corresponding futex system call?

With `/proc/525/maps` I find that the address 0x4a6f4 is part of the heap memory:

```
00008000-00019000 r-xp 00000000 00:10 6906       /root/dotnet/dotnet
00021000-00022000 r--p 00011000 00:10 6906       /root/dotnet/dotnet
00022000-00023000 rw-p 00012000 00:10 6906       /root/dotnet/dotnet
00023000-001c6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
a545c000-a545d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
...
```

But how can I relate this address back to a line of code? I have tried to run `gdb -p 525` but I am getting the error

```
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
```

Checking the libpthread library:

```
root@arm:~/dotnet# ldd /root/dotnet/dotnet
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6f16000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6ef2000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6de6000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6d6e000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6d45000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6c57000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f29000)
```

My .gdbinit file:

```
root@arm:~/dotnet# cat /root/.gdbinit
set auto-load safe-path /
set libthread-db-search-path /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
set env LD_PRELOAD /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
```

Therefore `where` or `bt` does not work in gdb:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0xb6f56344 in pthread_getattr_default_np (out=0xfffffff0) at pthread_getattr_default_np.c:34
#1  0xb2bdf998 in ?? ()
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have similar issue, application just stops with strace log showing futex as the last system call. Did yoi find out something (no answer here, yet)